# how to provide an input for whiptail using commhe and line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, heredoc

So, I have to setup several server that requires mysql-server on each and every one of them. I decided to write a shell script to enter a input to whiptail which require the user to input password. I wrote the bash script but it just does not response when it reach the whiptail page, can anyone help me with this? Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install mysql-server <<< "yes
mypassword
"
```

First when the sudo apt-get ask about whether to install or not it supplies yes, but then when it came to whiptail it does not provide any input as it should be which is `mypassword`

[image]

Comment: Don't understand. I didn't see any `whiptail` calling in the above. If you mean why the `sudo` doesn't accepts the password from the stdin, read the `man sudo` and learn about the `-S` or about the `-A`.

Comment: @jm666 Hi I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than providing input to whiptail, you can run `apt-get install` like this to skip prompts during installation:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

If you want to provide a root password as well, you can do this:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"

sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password myrootpw"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password myrootpw"

sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

Take care to not accidentally expose your root password (i.e. ensure it doesn't end up in your history, securely delete any script files containing it, I'm sure there are others).

I found this information [here](https://serversforhackers.com/video/installing-mysql-with-debconf).